Property of Sums of Squares in Weisberg
In Applied Linear Regression by Weisberg, on p. 23, I see this relation for $S_{xx}$:
$$
\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \sum(x_i - \bar{x})x_i
$$
Would someone explain why this equality holds?

Because $\sum_i (x_i-\bar x) =0.$

Use $(a-b)^2=(a-b)a - (a-b)b$

The second term simplifies.

Great insights! Thank you both.

I find it easiest to work each side through some algebra until both equal a common expression.
LEFT
$$
\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2\\
=\sum(x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)\\
=\sum(x_i^2-2\bar xx_i + \bar x^2)\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2\bar x\sum x_i + \sum\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2\bar x(n\bar x) + n\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2n\bar x^2 + n\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - n\bar x^2
$$
RIGHT
$$
\sum(x_i - \bar x)x_i\\
=\sum(x_i^2 - \bar x x_i)\\
=\sum x_i^2 - \bar x\sum x_i\\
=\sum x_i^2 - \bar xn\bar x\\
=\sum x_i^2 - n\bar x^2\\
$$
Since each side equals this $\sum x_i^2 - n\bar x^2$, the two sides must be equal.
$\square$
OVERALL, the algebra could be worked out as follows.
$$
\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2\\
=\sum(x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)\\
=\sum(x_i^2-2\bar xx_i + \bar x^2)\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2\bar x\sum x_i + \sum\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2\bar x(n\bar x) + n\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - 2n\bar x^2 + n\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - n\bar x^2\\
=\sum x_i^2 - \bar xn\bar x\\
=\sum x_i^2 - \bar x\sum x_i\\
=\sum(x_i^2 - \bar x x_i)\\
=\sum(x_i - \bar x)x_i
$$

$$\sum_i (x_i - \overline x)^2 = \sum_i (x_i - \overline x)x_i$$
This holds because $\displaystyle \sum_i (x_i-\overline x) = 0,$ i.e. the sum of deviations from the average is $0.$ Thus:
\begin{align}
& (x_i-\overline x)^2 = (x_i-\overline x)(x_i-\overline x) \\[8pt]
= {} & (x_i-\overline x)x_i - {} \underbrace{ (x_i - \overline x)\overline x}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{The sum of} \\ \text{these is 0.} \end{smallmatrix}}.
\end{align}
(Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{i\,=\,1}^n\Big( (x_i-\overline x)\overline x\Big) = \Big( \sum_{i\,=\,1}^n (x_i-\overline x)\Big) \overline x$ because $\overline x$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n.$)

Sometimes simple problems like this matter for this poses confusion for a beginner and since this question is asked frequently, directly or indirectly, this thread could be used as a possible duplicate (and yes, upvoted).
